# Java service can't be called using Acceleo

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, code-generation, acceleo

I've defined a custom meta-model using EMF Ecore and now I'm writing an acceleo project to generate proper java code.

Acceleo is not enough for several use cases, mainly searching the model for specific elements and holding extra information for some, so I need to call a custom Java service, and I followed the step-by-step example and I believe I know exactly how to write a query to invoke a Java service.

The problem is that when I call a service with Java primitive parameters it runs smoothly but when I write one with meta-model types I get the following error:

```
org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.AcceleoEvaluationException: argument type mismatch
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.environment.AcceleoLibraryOperationVisitor.invoke(AcceleoLibraryOperationVisitor.java:1001)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.environment.AcceleoLibraryOperationVisitor.callNonStandardOperation(AcceleoLibraryOperationVisitor.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitOperationCallExp(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1213)
    at org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.impl.OperationCallExpImpl.accept(OperationCallExpImpl.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.ocl.AbstractEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AbstractEvaluationVisitor.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.ocl.EvaluationVisitorDecorator.visitExpression(EvaluationVisitorDecorator.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1885)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitAcceleoQueryInvocation(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1862)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitAcceleoIfBlock(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1823)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitAcceleoTemplate(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1817)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitAcceleoTemplateInvocation(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:965)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1856)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitAcceleoIfBlock(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1823)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitAcceleoForBlock(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1833)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitAcceleoTemplate(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1817)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitAcceleoTemplateInvocation(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:965)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1856)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitAcceleoIfBlock(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1823)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitAcceleoFileBlock(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1846)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitAcceleoTemplate(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1817)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitAcceleoTemplateInvocation(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:965)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1856)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitAcceleoTemplate(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.switchExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1817)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.evaluation.AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.visitExpression(AcceleoEvaluationVisitor.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.ocl.internal.evaluation.QueryImpl.evaluate(QueryImpl.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.QueryImpl.evaluate(QueryImpl.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.generation.AcceleoEngine.doEvaluate(AcceleoEngine.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.generation.AcceleoEngine.evaluate(AcceleoEngine.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AcceleoService.doGenerateTemplate(AcceleoService.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AcceleoService.doGenerate(AcceleoService.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AbstractAcceleoGenerator.generate(AbstractAcceleoGenerator.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AbstractAcceleoGenerator.doGenerate(AbstractAcceleoGenerator.java:158)
    at com.muazothman.mobile.metamodel.android_converter.Main.doGenerate(Main.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.ide.ui.launching.strategy.AcceleoLaunchOperation.run(AcceleoLaunchOperation.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2326)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.ide.ui.launching.strategy.AcceleoPluginLaunchingStrategy.launch(AcceleoPluginLaunchingStrategy.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.ide.ui.launching.strategy.AcceleoPluginLaunchingStrategy.launch(AcceleoPluginLaunchingStrategy.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.internal.ide.ui.launching.AcceleoLaunchDelegate.launch(AcceleoLaunchDelegate.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.environment.AcceleoLibraryOperationVisitor.invoke(AcceleoLibraryOperationVisitor.java:993)
    ... 66 more
```

Anyone knows what's wrong?

here's the java code:

```
public void f(CustomAction c){
}
```

here's the mtl code

```
[query public f(arg0 : CustomAction) : OclVoid
    = invoke('converter.services.ActivityServices', 'f(metamodel.CustomAction)', Sequence{arg0.oclAsType(CustomAction)}) /]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your service actually located in a package converter.services, and the generated class CustomAction actually located in a package "metamodel"?

By the way, you should call

```
[query public f(arg0 : CustomAction) : OclVoid
    = invoke('converter.services.ActivityServices', 'f(metamodel.CustomAction)', Sequence{arg0}) /]
```

there's no need to explicitely cast it to CustomAction since it is declared as such.

Comment: Yes and thank you I'm aware there is no need for the casting, just was experimenting with code hoping to get invalid cast exception